# (float) in c / c++

Tags: c++, c

Trying to find out what the (float) in this function means:

```
static float avgEndpoints (int i, int stride, float *fa)
{
    return ((float) (fa[i-stride] +
                 fa[i+stride]) * .5f);
}
```

The reason I'm confused is the function already returns floating point (or appears to), so what is the (float) doing there?

I'm attempting to port this program to another language and learn a bit of c/c++ at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: summing two floats results in float, It seems the (float) is not necessary

Comment: Don't try and learn C/C++, there is no such language. There are many differences between C and C++ and the same code in each language can do different things. Even more importantly what is good practice in C and C++ is very different, so it's difficult to become a good programmer in both languages when you are trying to learn both languages at the same time.

Comment: @john It seems `C/C++` is one of those things that works much better in practice than it does in theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(float)` is a cast, which in this example casts the expression `(fa[i-stride] + fa[i+stride])` to floating point.

In this case the cast is redundant and not required (as the expression will be a float anyway due to the `*.5f`)

Comment: But the expression already is floating point, which is probably what is confusing alphablender.

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming, possibly incorrectly, that `static float avgEndpoints` should force floating point already?

Comment: @alphablender: incorrect, the return type would only apply after any expressions. The key here is the actual multiply by 0.5f, otherwise all other math would be performed as integer.

Comment: Generally speaking, the expression will not necessarily be float because of 0.5f, it depends on all the types involved in the expression. Had any of them been double, the result would have been double too.

Comment: @Lundin: Correct. Aren't type systems fun?

Comment: The important thing here when programming in C is to know that the order of evaluation is implementation defined. If you write A + B + C, then the compiler may evaluate it either as (A+B)+C or A+(B+C). Now, if A is an int, B is an int and C is a float, the A+B addition could be done on ints, which could possibly be a serious bug (overflow etc). And it will give a different result on different C compilers.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is useless in this context. The intent was to have/cast return value as float, but

```
(fa[i-stride] + fa[i+stride]) * .5f
```

is already a float so, don't see any reason for another `(float)` which is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's redundant; you don't really need it there, but you might have if for some reason the compiler was trying to make that a double or something, which it would have done if it read ".5" instead of ".5f".

You can safely remove it without changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

That "(float)" is called a cast. It forces the compiler to treat the result that follows as a float regardless of what it would otherwise be. For more information see [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

Answer (score 1):

It is a redundant cast, just as the outer parenthesis is redundant. I would too ask the programmer who has written that code why they are doing what they do. It appears that they were not sure how the C language works.

Completely equivalent but clearer code:

```
return (fa[i-stride] + fa[i+stride]) * .5f;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code**

`(float)` is a cast, which will force the expression `fa[i-stride] + fa[i+stride]` to be converted to a `float`.

For this code, this is a case of throwing in an unnecessary extra cast - just like throwing in an extra pair of parentheses (which this code also does).

I'd recommend removing extra unneeded parentheses, and learning the C++ standard order of operations/type promotions.

**Cases where you'd need a cast**

If that `fa[i-stride] + fa[i+stride]` expression returned a `double` instead, then there may be a subtle floating-point difference if you remove the cast.

Also if `fa[i-stride] + fa[i+stride]` returned an integral type, then it is sometimes possible you'd need to cast to float to ensure that the answer wouldn't be integral-truncated.

However, the C++ standard's order of operations/type promotion determines whether this will happen or not.  If those rules make the cast unnecessary, then you can (and probably should) take them out.

Comment: so would (float) function similar to the int() function in other languages where it forces whatever is in the parenthesis to be an int? like `float(fa[i-stride] + fa[i+stride])`

Comment: @alpha: Almost - it forces it to be a `float`.  The `int()` function you described is also in C++ - it is constructor-syntax for a cast-to-int.